# Anomaly dectection algorithm for time series univariate dataset

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, analytics, anomaly-detection

I have univariate time series data and I need to run anomaly detection algorithm on the same. Can anyone suggest any standard algorithm for anomaly detection which works in most cases?

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: This [link](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/1142/60072) might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such algorithm "*which works in most cases*". The task heavily depends on the specifics of your case, e.g. whether you need local anomalies when a point differs from other points near it or global ones when a point does not look similar to any other point in the dataset.

The very good review of anomaly detection algorithms can be found [here](http://www.goldiges.de/publications/Comparison_Unsupervised_Anomaly_Detection.pdf)

Perhaps you can easily try *one-class-SVM* which is available in many libraries and programming languages. For instance, in Python you can use [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_oneclass.html).